# When I click on Login button multiple times It loads the other page same number of times the button is clicked.how can I prevent this?

Tags: angular, ionic2

When I Click Login button several times before the pages gets navigated after pressing login button, It opens the page equal number of time as that of Login buttton pressed.
For example: When I click on login button it is navigated to page xyz.
Suppose I click 10 times in succession the login button then page xyz will open 10 times and then I have to press 10 times to logout xyz.
How can I prevent this?And what is the reason behind this?
The application is developed on ionic2 and angular2.
If any further information is needed please let me know.
Screenshot is attached with  this.[image: Screenshot]
My Code:
`

```
<ion-content padding>
  <form (submit)="onLogin()">
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label stacked color="secondary">Email</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="email" required [(ngModel)]="email" name="email"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label stacked color="secondary">Password</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="password" required minlength="6" maxlength="10" name="password" [(ngModel)]="password"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <br>
    <button ion-button color="secondary" block class="abc" type="submit">Login</button>
  </form>`
```

Comment: Proper way to do this is showing a loading control when the login operation is performed.

Comment: Thank you @Math10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like @Math10 suggested, a better way to handle this would be by showing a [loading indicator](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/loading/LoadingController/#loading-controller):

> An overlay that can be used to indicate activity **while blocking user
>   interaction**.

This way, you'd not only block user interaction, but also the user would get some feedback and would know that something is happening.

```
public onLogin(): void {
  let loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
    content: 'Please wait...'
  });

  // Show the loading indicator
  loading.present();

  // your code...

  // After the server returns a response, you can hide the loading indicator
  loading.dismiss().then(() => {
    // here you can redirect the user to the next page or show an error
  });
}
```

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 2):

Disable the button from clicking again

```
<button (click)="login()" [disabled]="disableButton"> </button>


login(){
  .....
  this.disableButton= true;
}
```

Comment: I have placed my code, shall I place the same thing here that you suggested?@Aravind

Comment: `this.disableButton = true;` shows disableButton property is not found.

Comment: Property is `disabled` and not `disabledButton`